# How to add gaps to a JTree

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jtree

my problem is this

I'm trying create a component that displays two tree side by side. The two trees will generally be very similar but will probably have one or two differences. Where there is a difference, ie a branch in one but not in the other, I would like the tree without the branch to show an empty space for it, and for each of its missing children too.

So it might look something like

```
left tree        right tree
------------     -------------
+ Root           + Root
|                |
--Child A        --Child A
|                | 
--Child B        |
|                |
--Child C        --Child C
```

Its relatively straight forward to remove the text and icon for those rows that should be gaps using a custom renderer. However, this still leaves the horizontal line that connects a child to the parents vertical line. And this is my problem.

```
left tree        right tree
------------     -------------
+ Root           + Root
|                |
--Child A        --Child A
|                | 
--Child B        --  <--I want to remove this
|                |
--Child C        --Child C
```

It's maybe bareable in this simple example but when the missing branch has children too I end up with lots of small lines connecting gaps.

A potential alternative I think is to create a one column JTreeTable for each tree and blank out the cells for the missing branches. Although this will mean that a portion of the vertical line will also be lost.

Any help, ideas or comments will be very much appriciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
class ReticentTreeUI extends BasicTreeUI {

    private Set<Integer> hiddenRows = new HashSet<Integer>();

    public void hideRow(int row) {
        hiddenRows.add(row);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintHorizontalPartOfLeg(Graphics g,
        Rectangle clipBounds, Insets insets, Rectangle bounds,
        TreePath path, int row, boolean isExpanded,
        boolean hasBeenExpanded, boolean isLeaf) {
        if (!hiddenRows.contains(row)) {
            super.paintHorizontalPartOfLeg(g, clipBounds, insets, bounds,
                path, row, isExpanded, hasBeenExpanded, isLeaf);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintRow(Graphics g, Rectangle clipBounds,
        Insets insets, Rectangle bounds, TreePath path, int row,
        boolean isExpanded, boolean hasBeenExpanded, boolean isLeaf) {
        if (!hiddenRows.contains(row)) {
            super.paintRow(g, clipBounds, insets, bounds, path, row,
                isExpanded, hasBeenExpanded, isLeaf);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintExpandControl(Graphics g, Rectangle clipBounds,
        Insets insets, Rectangle bounds, TreePath path, int row,
        boolean isExpanded, boolean hasBeenExpanded, boolean isLeaf) {
        if (!hiddenRows.contains(row)) {
            super.paintExpandControl(g, clipBounds, insets, bounds,
                path, row, isExpanded, hasBeenExpanded, isLeaf);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
    JTree tree = new JTree();
    ReticentTreeUI ui = new ReticentTreeUI();
    tree.setUI(ui);
    ui.hideRow(2);
```